# Remove DataTable From DataSet doesn't work

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, dataset

I have problem with "undeletable" DataTable.

**Step 1: I create DataTable**

```
DataTable dt = dtProgPoints_Template.Clone(); //Create table
dt.TableName = "Program points 0"; //Rename it
dsProgPoints.Tables.Add(dt); //Add it to DataSet
dsProgPoints.AcceptChanges(); //I found it in this forum, so I tried it
```

**Step 2: I display it in DataGridView**

```
dtgProgPoints.DataSource = dsProgPoints; //dtgProgPoints is my DataGridView
dtgProgPoints.DataMember = "Program points 0";
```

**Step 3: Remove DataTable**

```
dsProgPoints.Tables.Remove("Program points 0"); //Remove DataTable from dataset
ds.AcceptChanges();//I found it in this forum, so I tried it
```

And now, the mystery is coming.

If I check `dsProgPoints.Tables.Count;`, Table is removed, number of tables is smaller than before removing.

When I try delete it again, exception occurs.

But when I try `dtgProgPoints.DataMember = "Program points 0";`, All data are displayed in DataGridView. Table still is not a member of table collection in DataSet, because if I Try to read it `dsProgPoints.Tables["Program points 0"].Rows[0][0]` an exception is fired, because table "Program points 0" is not a member of table collection.

When I create it again using `dsProgPoints.Tables.Add("Program points 0");` Table is created. It means, it really does not exist in DataSet

It looks like there is some problem with `DataGridView`? 
Tahnk You, Pavel